# How to update a listbox by using a sub procedure

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a user form and a listbox on that, I am using the listbox as activity memo, I developed a sub for updating that listbox and also a listobject in a sheet as its bank. (the listbox just have the current session logs, but list object have all the records). I can't pass the listbox control to the sub. I tried it in a module and also in the userform code section, but I can't refer listbox name (not as a string nor as a listbox control). Do you have any idea or sollution for this? 
Here is my code.

```
Public Sub memoadd(ByVal txt As String, ByVal tablename As String, ByVal listbox As String)
    Dim lrow As ListRow, lobj As ListObject, lstbox As listbox

    Set lobj = log.ListObjects(tablename)
    Set lrow = lobj.ListRows.Add(1, True)
    Set lstbox = Me.Controls(listbox)
    lstbox.AddItem txt & " @ " & Format(Time, "hh:mm"), "0"

    With lrow
       lrow.Range(1, 1) = lobj.ListRows.Count
       lrow.Range(1, 2) = Now
       lrow.Range(1, 3) = lstbox.List(0)
       lrow.Range(1, 4) = Environ$("Computername")
       lrow.Range(1, 5) = Environ$("username")
    End With

    lstbox.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Here is how I am using that in my procedures.

```
memoadd "master file of A/C: " & ac & " is opened", "Logs", "ListBox2"
```

Comment: I also tried putting the userform name instead of me, but no luck

Comment: The _reason_ your code fails is `Dim lstbox as listbox` should be `Dim lstbox as MSForms.ListBox`.  `ListBox` and `MSForms.ListBox` are not the same type

Comment: Thanks, Chris you catch the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to (make sure) access the `ListBox` at runtime.
Meaning the `Userform` is already loaded when you call the `Sub`.

Another suggestion in your `Sub`, instead of passing `ListBox` as `String`, pass it as `MSForms.ListBox` Object. Something like this:

```
Public Sub memoadd(ByVal txt As String, _
                   ByVal tablename As String, _
                   ByVal listbox As MSForms.ListBox) 

listbox.AddItem txt & " @ " & Format(Time, "hh:mm"), "0"
'/* no need to set lobj here, you can use listbox directly */
'/* rest of your code */

End Sub
```

I hope this gets you going, you didn't mention other specifics regarding your code.
 And so I didn't check and assumed it should work.